# How can I determine if the clock has 2 or 3 hands

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to calculate the time in an analog clock. Got some test images, and everything works fine when the clock has 2 hands. I'm using Hough LinesP, then I stack the lines, then K-Means with 2 K-s. I can detect 3 hands almost perfectly every time, but then it messes up when the clock has 2 hands and vice-versa. Here are some input images, and the detected lines:

Test Input 1:

| Input 1 | Detection with K = 2 | Detection with K = 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Test Input 1] | [image: Segment with 2 as K] | [image: Segment with 3 as K] |

K = 3 (I know, this is not a big difference, but I got way worse test's where the extra line just messes up everything)

---

Test Input 2:

| Input 2 | Detection with K = 2 | Detection with K = 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Test Input 2] | [image: Segment with 2 as K] | [image: Segment with 3 as K] |

So as you see, I can detect the hands, but I dont know when to use 2 as K, and when to use 3. Any thoughts?

Comment: idk if kmeans is the best solution here, but from what i can see the hands will always be a different width, so if you can check if there are lines with different widths, that will tell you how many hands you have. but to do that check you might already have the hands so you wouldnt need kmeans unless you want a more accurate result that what you got